# Can I use IIS host-header binding to avoid having to use port number in url

Tags: asp.net, iis

Is it possible to configure host header binding of site in IIS to a particular port so that users do not have to specify the port number in a url?

This is for an intranet site.  We have several sites hosted on the one server each with their own host name with DNS entries which point to the same machine name.

I have tried specifying host-header name (site-specific hostname), unique port number and "*" for IP address, but to access the site I still have to specify the port number in the browser.

I was hoping that binding the site to the unique host name would be enough to resolve the site without having to specify the port number in the url.

Thanks.

Comment: `I was hoping that binding the site to the unique host name would be enough to resolve the site without having to specify the port number in the url.` it's enough for standard ports 80(http) and 443(https). web clients don't know  what's your web server's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a redirect.

What I would do, if there is no querystring is have a binding for the same domain in one of the standard ports 80 or 443 if you use SSL. Then use IIS Redirect to redirect all requests to the URL with the custom port.

Another way would be to use URL Rewrite to do the redirects so you can keep the querystring. For example [10 URL Rewriting tips and tricks](http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/)